# Chocolatey can't find windows feature

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy, chocolatey

I'm using Octopus deploy to run a PowerShell script on a destination machine, attempting to install `IIS`. I'm using the script below and passing in the necessary parameters. What gets logged makes be believe the call is being made correctly, but it simply responds with:

Installing package `IIS-WebServerRole` from the `Chocolatey` package repository...

```
17:11:48Info
Installing the following packages:
17:11:48Info
IIS-WebServerRole
17:11:48Info
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
17:11:48Info
IIS-WebServerRole not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
17:11:48Info
 If you specified a particular version and are receiving this message, it is possible that the package name exists but the version does not.
17:11:48Info
 Version: ""
17:11:48Info
 Source(s): "windowsFeatures"
```

Code:

```
$chocolateyBin = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ChocolateyInstall", "Machine") + "\bin"
if(-not (Test-Path $chocolateyBin)) {
    Write-Output "Environment variable 'ChocolateyInstall' was not found in the system variables. Attempting to find it in the user variables..."
    $chocolateyBin = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ChocolateyInstall", "User") + "\bin"
}

$cinst = "$chocolateyBin\cinst.exe"
$choco = "$chocolateyBin\choco.exe"

if (-not (Test-Path $cinst) -or -not (Test-Path $choco)) {
    throw "Chocolatey was not found at $chocolateyBin."
}

if (-not $ChocolateyPackageId) {
    throw "Please specify the ID of an application package to install."
}

$chocoVersion = & $choco --version
Write-Output "Running Chocolatey version $chocoVersion"

$chocoArgs = @()
if([System.Version]::Parse($chocoVersion) -ge [System.Version]::Parse("0.9.8.33")) {
    Write-Output "Adding --confirm to arguments passed to Chocolatey"
    $chocoArgs += @("-y", "")
}

if($ChocolateyPackageSource) {
    Write-Output "Adding --source to arguments passed to Chocolatey"
    $chocoArgs += @("-source", $ChocolateyPackageSource)
}

if (-not $ChocolateyPackageVersion) {
    Write-Output "Installing package $ChocolateyPackageId from the Chocolatey package repository..."
    & $cinst $ChocolateyPackageId $($chocoArgs)
} else {
    Write-Output "Installing package $ChocolateyPackageId version $ChocolateyPackageVersion from the Chocolatey package repository..."
    & $cinst $ChocolateyPackageId -version $ChocolateyPackageVersion $($chocoArgs)
}
```

Based on the most recent Chocolatey documentation I can find, this should work. Any ideas why it wouldn't? I should mention this is on an Azure Windows 2012 R2 VM.

Comment: Could you not run a powershell script on the box manually running as a user under which the tentacle is running?

Comment: @AlexM - Yeah I get the exact same message even if I log onto the machine as an admin.  It appears that the windows features commands just aren't working.  I even tried some old versions of the calls which also didn't work.  I'm new at using Chocolatey so thought perhaps I was doing something obviously wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working by bumping to the prerelease version of chocolatey.  9.10.x-beta...

I should note that just doing a -pre was not enough to get it to install the package...for some reason I had to also -force the package to get chocolatey to update itself. Not sure if this is by design.

Comment: Definitely not by design. If you have any logs of it not working, I'd love to take a look. Side note, `choco upgrade chocolatey -pre`, NOT `choco install chocolatey -pre`/`cinst chocolatey -pre`. The second two commands would require `--force` because install is about getting something install, upgrade is from then on. HTH. Let me know if it was something else.

Comment: I did confirm I am doing an upgrade...not sure why the force was necessary, I'll send some logs if I do this again.

Comment: Cool - keep in mind logs are taken in debug/verbose format. So that's helpful when you want to take a look.